# Exiftool in Rails app running on Heroku not pulling EXIF consistently

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, exiftool

I have a Rails app running on Heroku, using the mini_exiftool and paperclip gems. I've installed the BUILDPACK for the exiftool.

App tests successfully on localhost. But on heroku, photos taken with a camera will scrape EXIF data properly. Photos uploaded with an iPhone (or other smart phones as far as I can tell) the fields are nil.

Answer (score 0):

Can be because Heroku doesn't have the Exiftool Perl Library, try with the [mini_exiftool_vendored](https://github.com/wilg/mini_exiftool_vendored) gem instead.